# 'NpgsqlBinaryImporter' does not contain a definition for 'Cancel'

Tags: npgsql

As I write this, the documentation at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html#cancel says:

> Import operations can be cancelled at any time by calling the Cancel()
>   method on the importer object. No data is committed to the database
>   before the importer is closed or disposed.
>
> Export operations can be cancelled as well, also by calling Cancel().

I just updated my Npgsql package from 3.1.10 to 4.0.7, and now I get the error `'NpgsqlBinaryImporter' does not contain a definition for 'Cancel'` for code similar to the following:

```
void WriteStuff(IEnumerable<RowInfo> enumerable, NpgsqlConnection conn)
{
    using (var writer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("COPY blah blah FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)"))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var rowInfo in enumerable)
            {
                writer.StartRow();
                writer.Write(...); // blah blah
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            writer.Cancel();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like [this commit](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/commit/a4039a3b5c3faf9b7a74afb800e2060bab325b55#diff-1fe10fccfab679c43f0e7eaaa1a48ea8) made Cancel() private.

So what is the correct way to cancel a bulk operation now? Do I need to wrap it in a transaction?

[And given the answer, I should just get rid of the try-catch code in the above code and just let the exception happen. Also the call to writer.Close() should change to writer.Complete(). ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npgsql 4.0 changed the COPY API around cancellation in a significant way, [see the release notes](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/4.0.html#breaking-changes-from-32).

In a nutshell, you must now explicitly call `Complete()` on NpgsqlBinaryImporter in order to commit the import; disposing it without calling `Complete()` will cancel the operation. This was done in order to make sure that exceptions don't cause a commit, and is aligned with how .NET TransactionScope work.

I'll update the documentation on this - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? It looks to me like Dispose() calls Close() which "Completes the import process and signals to the database to write everything."

Comment: Look at the code rather than at the XML documentation - it sends a CopyFailMessage to cancel the import.

Comment: Okay - thanks - would it be possible to request that the XML documentation be made more clear?